# lodash, get matched element's index?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Here is my case

```
var myArray = [undefined, true, false, true];
```

I want to get the items' index, which value is true. With above array, the result should be

```
[1, 3]
```

as the 2nd and 4th item equal true.
How can I find the matched items' index with lodash?

Thanks

Comment: `[...myArray.entries()].filter(([, v]) => v).map(([i]) => i);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is the first way that came to mind using vanilla JS:

```js
var myArray = [undefined, true, false, true];

var result = myArray.map((v,i) => v ? i : -1).filter(v => v > -1);

console.log(result);
```

Or if you don't want to use arrow functions:

```
var result = myArray.map(function(v,i) { return v ? i : -1; })
                    .filter(function(v) { return v > -1; });
```

That is, first map the original array to output the index of true elements and -1 for other elements, then filter that result to only keep the ones that aren't -1.

Note that the map function `(v,i) => v ? i : -1` is testing for truthy elements  - if you need only elements that are the boolean `true` then use `(v,i) => v===true ? i : -1`.

I guess the Lodash equivalent of that would be as follows (edit: thanks to zerkms for much improved syntax):

```js
var myArray = [undefined, true, false, true];

var result = _(myArray).map((v,i) => v ? i : -1).filter(v => v > -1).value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Btw `_(myArray).map(...).filter(...).value()`

Comment: @zerkms - Sorry, editing at the same time to credit your contribution, I wasn't trying to undo your edit. Although after accidentally undoing your edit I noticed that it seems to produce the same result without the `.value()` part - why is that?

Comment: It is a SO console emulator that does some additional magic. If you go to a normal browser console you would see it returns some intermediate lodash wrapper.

Comment: @zerkms - Cool. I figured there was a Lodash wrapper, but didn't think about how the SO console emulator would change things.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
// lodash 

x = _(myArray).map(Array).filter(0).map(1).value()

// vanilla

x = myArray.map(Array).filter(a => a[0]).map(a => a[1])
```

Comment: That's educational thanks! Never thought to use lodash#filter and lodash#map that way. I thought they'd only work on object matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
// lodash
var myArray = [undefined, true, false, true];
var indexes = _.reduce(myArray, (result, val, index) => {
    if (val) {
        result.push(index);
    }
    return result;
}, []);
```